# Aspect mock does not overload method in codeception

Tags: php, codeception

I have such files:

/src/Api.php

```
<?php

namespace src;

class Api {
    function apiCall()
    {
        return 'api_result';
    }
}
```

/tests/_bootstrap.php

```
<?php

include __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; // composer autoload

$kernel = \AspectMock\Kernel::getInstance();
$kernel->init([
    'debug' => true,
    'includePaths' => [__DIR__.'/../src'],
    'cacheDir' => __DIR__ . '/aspectCache'
]);
```

codeception.yml

```
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed

settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
```

composer.json

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "codeception/aspect-mock": "*",
        "codeception/codeception": "^2.3"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use src\Api;

$api = new Api();
echo $api->apiCall();
echo 'test';
```

/tests/acceptance/FirstCest.php

```
<?php

use AspectMock\Test as test;
use src\Api;

class FirstCest
{
    public function frontpageWorks(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('/');

        test::double(Api::class, ['apiCall' => 'mock']);

        $I->see('mocktest');
    }
}
```

When I load page in browser I see string 'api_resulttest'

Now when I mock the apiCall function, the output should be 'mocktest'.

I run command

```
php codecept.phar run --steps -d
```

And test fails, I still see the output 'api_resulttest'.

Why? And do I use it correctly? https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock here it does not show how to use it in codeception tests.

Or please tell another way - how should I mock api calls in codeception? Thats what I want to do.

I have pushed into bitbucket so you can test the example: 
https://bitbucket.org/darius_v/codeception_mock/src

**Update 2017 10 01** 
Now removed aspect mock in my newest commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhpBrowser makes request to your website over HTTP, so the mocks set in the test code have no effect over app code.

The mocks work in unit tests and in functional tests if you are using a framework module.

Comment: Ok, but if I do not have framework like in this test app, there still should be possible to mock, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you use a regular unit test instead of using PhpBrowser.